# Include the URL of a related entry field

Tags: entry, url, relatedto

I would like to add the URL of the channel entry I have selected (atm 2 channels are available to choose from), so I would like a url like:

**summerhouses**/product1

or

**greehnouses**/product2

how would I modify the code below to achieve this?

The code below just shows: /product1

```
{% for row in entry.homeFeaturedProducts.order('RAND()')|batch(4) %}
{% for entry in row %}
    <h2 class="product-card-title"><a href="{{ entry.getUrl }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
    <span class="product-card-desc">Product Description</span>
    <span class="product-card-price">{{ entry.price }}</span>
{% endfor %}        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - using {{ entry.section }} and {{ entry.slug }}

```
{% for row in entry.homeFeaturedProducts.order('RAND()')|batch(4) %}
{% for entry in row %}
    <h2 class="product-card-title"><a href="{{ entry.section}}/{{ entry.slug }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
    <span class="product-card-desc">Product Description</span>
    <span class="product-card-price">{{ entry.price }}</span>
{% endfor %}        
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work, but I now need to get the template to match with the url as the slug consists of 2 parts (which is what I wanted) and using an entry-type template which matches the section is throwing a 404:

entry type handle is 'products'

and the template name is also 'products' which works for urls with one slug but not for the additional as desired?

Comment: I just changed the section url format setting to:

{section}/{slug}

and sorted